# How to manage external permission when installing in the wrong order?

Tags: android, permissions

I have two applications, *MyService* and *MyLauncher* :

- *MyService*  have a local database, and a provider allowing another app to save data into it, with the permission `toto.myservice.WRITE_DATABASE`
- *MyLauncher* can push data in the database of *MyService*

When I install *MyService* first, the new permission becomes known by Android, so there is no problem when I want to install *MyLauncher*, the permission is successfully given, and the data is inserted easily.

But if *MyLauncher* is installed first, this doesn't work, the permission is Unknown by the system.
I tried to manage it in the `OnCreate` like permissions in Android 6+, but it doesn't seem to work (`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` doesn't show any window)

In *MyService* (in the manifest) I declare the permission this way :

```
<permission android:name="toto.myservice.WRITE_DATABASE"android:label="M_WRITE_DB" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<provider android:name="MyContentProvider"
    android:authorities="toto.myservice.MyContentProvider"
    android:exported="true"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:writePermission="toto.myservice.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
```

In *MyLauncher* (in the manifest), I use permission this way :

```
<uses-permission android:name="toto.myservice.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
```

In the `OnCreate` in *MyLauncher*, I try to call

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"toto.myservice.WRITE_DATABASE"},
                    SERVICE_PRINTER_WRITE_DATABASE);
```

No window is displayed, and in the callback :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SERVICE_PRINTER_WRITE_DATABASE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "grantResults.length = " + grantResults.length);
                //====> I'm here, not granted
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

So my final question, if a user makes the installations in the wrong order, is it possible to call the permission without reinstall *MyLauncher* ?

Thanks

Comment: `new String[]{"fr.ca.cats.servicePrinter.WRITE_DATABASE"}`. Should not that be `new String[]{"toto.myservice.WRITE_DATABASE"}`?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to replace this one.. The problem is still the same